# Python how to restrict output type as dictionary?

Tags: python, return-type

I find an example.

```
from typing import List
def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    pass
```

So I'm trying to restrict the input as an integer, and the output as a dictionary. `survey = {"sid": survey_id, "title": 22}` this line work. However, `survey = [survey_id, 22]`, the return type becomes `list` also works. How can I fix it?

```
def question(survey_id: int) -> dict:
    #survey = {"sid": survey_id, "title": 22}
    survey = [survey_id, 22]
    return survey

question("3456")    
['3456', 22]
```

More specifically, I'd like to restrict the return type as a dictionary with integer and string only. How can I make it?

Comment: Python typing is just type hints, they're not enforced.

Comment: If you use a type analysis tool, it might be able to detect that you violated the type signature.

Comment: Can't be done - python will always be dynamically typed. As already noted, the best you can hope for is using type hints and some sort of third party tool to analyse the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python interpreter can't enforce that a function returns a specific type. If you want to prevent the program from executing when the types are not correctly defined, Python is not a good choice of language.

On the other hand, you can use a static typechecker like [`mypy`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to ensure that type hints are correctly observed. These type hints aren't enforced at runtime, but they can ensure that modifications to functions do not introduce typing-related bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this but in a slightly roundabout way. Although this way is very useful when you're working with any kind of an API. What you do is create an object and return this object where you can enforce data types.

Two best options for this are the dataclasses which are a part of standard library since 3.8 (I think) or a better option is to use Pydantic which is also like a dataclass but comes with plenty of additional features.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Survey(BaseModel):
    sid: int
    title: str

def survey_result(id: int) -> Survey:
    res = Survey(sid=id, title='foo')
    return res
```

Now Pydantic will enforce data types. For example:

```
>>> survey_result(11)
Out: Survey(sid=11, title='foo')

>>> survey_result('blabla')
Out: 
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Survey
sid  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

Pydantic is also optimised for web APIs and can work to convert data types if necessary. Say, you were supposed to have an integer but then result is returned as a json and for whatever reason the integer becomes a string. Pydantic can deal with this:

```
>>> survey_result('11')
Out: Survey(sid=11, title='foo')
```